How do you loop the typewriter effect in Next.js?
I have this typewriter effect in my project; however, it only types once. I want the typewriter effect to be on loop. Like, I want it to start over and type the words again. I've been searching online for a solution, and there are sources that comes close to solving my problem, but I don't know how to incorporate their code into mine. A source would be This. This is my code:
"use client";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

let i = 0;
let txt = "This is the text that will be typed.";
let speed = 50;
let loop = true;

export default function Home() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const headerMessage = document.getElementById("header-message");
    if (headerMessage && i < txt.length) {
      const typeWriter = setInterval(() => {
        headerMessage.innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
        i++;
      }, speed);
      return () => clearInterval(typeWriter);
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <main>
      <section>
        <section>
          <p id="header-message"></p>
        </section>
        <section></section>
      </section>
    </main>
  );
}


Add this below i++:
if ((i > txt.length) && loop) {
    headerMessage.innerHTML = "";
    i = 0;
}

This simply resets the iterator to 0 and clears the message. If you want a delay before typing again, you can just add a setTimeout like below:
if ((i > txt.length) && loop) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        headerMessage.innerHTML = "";
        i = 0;
     }, 1000);
}

Replace 1000 with how long you want to wait in ms.
